# Questions every Smartphone(Iphone,Android) Developer should be able to answer?

Tags: java, iphone, android, objective-c, smartphone

I was going through Questions every good .Net developer should be able to answer and was highly impressed with the content and approach of this question, and so in the same spirit, I am asking this question for Smartphon(Iphone/Android) Developers.

What ***questions*** do you think should a ***good Smartphone (Iphone/Android) programmer*** be able to answer?

I am marking this question as community wiki as it is not user specific and it aims to serve programming community at large.

Looking forward for some amazing responses.

Please answer questions too,so that people could learn something new regarding the language, too.

Comment: I want this question to be community question, how can I can make it community question?

Comment: I believe this question would be worthy for different smartphone developers and so would appreciate if negative voter can justify his or her stand for marking question as negative?

Comment: Is this not the right place for such knowledge based questions? I have gone through other similar questions and SO Community had accepted those questions and so had asked this questions for Smart Phone Developers, I am open to delete this question if need be but would certainly appreciate some feedback in terms of comments from SO Community.

Comment: Answer to the Community Wiki question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts

Comment: Rachel, poll questions are no longer considered suitable for Stack Overflow. They were more common once, but got out of hand.  This *might* work over on programmers.stackexhange.com.

Comment: can you move it to programmers site?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it *is* suitable for p.se, so I didn't vote to migrate there. If this question isn't migrated, and you think it's suitable for p.se, you can post it there yourself. But review similar questions on that site there first, and the [FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq).